# How can I add a text label to a Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to add a text to my Floating Action Buttons, like name them or put a label next to them. I have tried so many ways but couldn't find a correct answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.chatdesign.Welcome">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout">
    </include>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:id="@id/Plus"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:fab_labelStyle="@style/customFab">

    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_add_24"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/FindPeople"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
        app:fab_title="Find Users">
    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_group_24"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/findGroup"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:fabSize="mini">

    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_start_group_24"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/startGroup"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:fabSize="mini">

    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the output of my project:

[image]

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Answer (score 1):

Use the extended floating action button class which is apart of the material design components library:

https://material.io/develop/android/components/extended-floating-action-button/

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android

Comment: Thanks i solved it :)